# JBoss EAP 6.3.0 errors in Eclipse Servers View

Tags: eclipse, ear, jboss-eap-6

I'm developing a **Java EE 6** application with **JBoss EAP 6.3.0** configured as an **Eclipse server**.

In the *Package Explorer* view all projects are compile-clean.

[image: projects in Eclipse Package Explorer]

But the *Servers* view shows error icons for the EJB modules and the EAR.

[image]

The application is working fine.

Why does the Eclipse Servers view show errors? 
Where can I find additional information about those errors? 
(The problems view is empty when I click on one of those modules)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, but looks like it was a matter of restarting Eclipse.